# Launch bamboo agent at startup on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, bamboo

In my situation I have an Ubuntu Server 16.04 and I want to launch a Bamboo remote agent at the startup of the machine.

I have already tried putting on `/etc/systemd/system/bamboo.service` this lines of code

```
[Unit]
Description=Bamboo Remote Agent Launcher

[Service]
User=bamboo
Group=bamboo
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/bin/bamboo-agent.sh start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but it seems not work, because my Bamboo do not see my agent and the systemctl status return this info

```
● bamboo.service - Bamboo Remote Agent Launcher
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bamboo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since mer 2018-05-09 16:28:07 CEST; 6s ago
Process: 2872 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/bin/bamboo-agent.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the code with:

```
[Unit]
Description=Atlassian Bamboo Agent
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=apps
Group=apps
ExecStart=/apps/bamboo-agent/bin/bamboo-agent.sh start
ExecStop=/apps/bamboo-agent/bin/bamboo-agent.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then reload and start it (as root or using sudo)

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start bamboo-agent
```

Res: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/How-to-I-install-bamboo-agent-as-a-daemon-under-Linux/qaq-p/393880

Comment: Ran into `timeout` issues on reboot. Changing `network.target` to `network-online.target` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the agent? Atlassian's Documentation sucks in this one.

You should install the agent  as bamboo user with the word "**install**" at the end.

```
java -jar atlassian-bamboo-agent-installer-6.7.2.jar https://my.bamboo-server.com/agentServer/ install
```

Replace with the address of your Server of course

Also if you run `journalctl -xe` you'll probably see something like

[image]

This means you have to go to your bamboo-server under your **agents** page and confirm the agent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have a shell script to start the remote agent that is called in a cron job that runs on reboot

launchRemoteAgent.sh
java -jar /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/atlassian-bamboo-agent-installer-6.6.3.jar http://:8085/agentServer/ > /home/bamboo/bamboo.log 2>&1 &

crontab
@reboot /home/bamboo/bin/launchRemoteAgent.sh > /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

Once you've run the agent for the first time it will create control scripts to install and manage the service.

So after running:

```
java -jar atlassian-bamboo-agent-installer-6.10.4.jar ...
```

Stop the agent and run:

```
sudo ./bamboo-agent-home/bin/bamboo-agent.sh install
```

Then you can control it with:

```
sudo service bamboo-agent [start|stop|restart|status]
```

Or you can call the agent script directly. Run the below to see all possible commands:

```
sudo ./bamboo-agent-home/bin/bamboo-agent.sh
```

The following command is useful to diagnose startup issues:

```
sudo ./bamboo-agent-home/bin/bamboo-agent.sh console
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent version of bamboo it doesn't need to create service config files manually. But unfortunately it doesn't well documented on [bamboo documents](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+documentation).

After you have installed bamboo agent and approve the agent on bamboo admin panel (see @DimiDak answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55137681/6463720):

1. Install bamboo agent service

```
YOUR/PATH/TO/bamboo-agent-home/bin/bamboo-agent.sh install
```

2. Enable the service

```
systemctl enable bamboo-agent
```

3. Start it

```
systemctl start bamboo-agent
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete guide for bamboo 8.1.3 is the following, Bamboo DC/server must be running and accessible by the agent, we are also using remote agent token instead of authorization(RHEL 8 - jdk already installed):

```
$ sudo useradd --create-home -c "Bamboo Agent role account" bamboo-agent
# define a password for bamboo-agent user if you want
$ sudo su - bamboo-agent
# get the jar installer from server
$ wget http://<your-bamboo-server/DC>:<your-port>/agentServer/agentInstaller/atlassian-bamboo-agent-installer-8.1.3.jar
# logout and become root again 
$ exit
# install the software in the bamboo-home dir
$ sudo java -Dbamboo.home=/home/bamboo-agent -jar /home/bamboo-agent/atlassian-bamboo-agent-installer-8.1.3.jar http://<your-bamboo-server/DC>:<your-port>/agentServer/ -t <your-token> install
# install the daemon for systemd
$ sudo /home/bamboo-agent/bin/bamboo-agent.sh install
# the installer will create files as root, so change the owner and the group
$ sudo chown -R bamboo-agent: /home/bamboo-agent/
# Change the user from the daemon
$ sudo sed -i '/^Type=.*/a User=bamboo-agent\nGroup=bamboo-agent' /etc/systemd/system/bamboo-agent.service
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl start bamboo-agent
```

Now you should be able to see the agent registered in the server. If not, login as the user(in our case bamboo-agent) and check the logs in the home dir.

/JGG